# PID of background task is different to the listed task PID using ps

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, pid

**Note:** I h ave moved this to stack-overflow, I think that is the right place: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275490/pid-of-background-task-is-different-to-the-listed-task-pid-using-ps)

I have a strange issue, I can't quite get my head around. What I do is run a function called fn_rundumper which basically just calls the bash code: 'pterm -z "cmd.sh" param1 &'

Here is the output of that, which includes the background pid "27938858":

```
fn_rundumper
running fn_dumper...
[1] 27938858
fn_dumper...done
```

Then I look at the job numbers that are running this also shows PID "27938858":

```
jobs -l
[1] + 27938858 Running              $(pterm -z "$SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $VO
```

Then I do a ps command to see what pterms are running:

```
ps | grep pterm
 24285189 ?        00:00:00 pterm
 27938859 ?        00:00:00 pterm
```

This yields the PID "27938859". This is different to the others!

When I kill PID 27938858 nothing seems to happen. When I kill PID 27938859 then the background pterm is closed.

The problem is that I may want to run many different background pterms as well as some pterms that are not opened as background tasks (i.e. run separately). So when I come to tidy up I just want to close the pterms that I have opened via my script.

I was trying to use jobs -l to see the PIDs I need to close, but as I just described this is the wrong PID.

Can anyone explain why this happens? and also what I need to do to get the correct PID?
Thanks!

**- edit -**
The best I can think of is to do a 'ps | grep pterm' before and after and compare the results to find the new pterm PID... do-able, but ugly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you are creating two processes, the first is that of your function `fn_rundumper`, and the second is that of `pterm` opened by your function. That's way your function call takes a pid ending with 858, and `pterm` called from your function takes the pid next after it, ending with 859.

As for the pid of the first `pterm`, it is that of the terminal you used to execute your function. That's why killing it will kill everything created in it (as long as you are not using the `nohup` command).

To see the same pid in a `ps` command, try:
`ps | grep run_dumper.sh`, which is the pid of the bash script that runs your `fn_rundumper` function.

Comment: Hi Linostar, This did not quite work, I don't think that running it from a function has any effect. But this did point me in an important direction. I tested it again all on the command line (no function call). When I use back-tick around the function it has the same behaviour. If I don't put back-tick around the function then the PIDs are all correct! i.e.: "`pterm -z "$VOE_SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $PROJECT_DIR` &" becomes: "pterm -z "$VOE_SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $PROJECT_DIR &" .... so back tick must be adding a PID level. ALso, sorry, I moved this into stack overflow, please see link

Comment: But +1 for that pointer : )

Comment: Were you using backticks? Yes, backticks will create a separate process as you already deduced. Glad to be able to help a bit.

Comment: Yes I was! - I only guessed what was happening, but its a strange behaviour. Your notes got me where I wanted to go thanks!